# cakephp: fetching matching records using email addr and displaying in the form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

When the user enters his email address, I want to check if his/her data is in the database table using the email addr. If it is there, it should fetch the matching records (initial, name, address, city, state, postal code) and display them in the form. If the email addr is not in the db table, the user should be allowed to fill in the rest of the form.

I'm using cakePHP and MYSQL for this project. Can this be done using AJAX? What is the best way to do the above?

Thank you.

Comment: i just want to know if AJAX and cakephp alone be suffient for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, Ajax and cakephp alone are sufficient. I have shown you exactly how (depending on your version of cake) below.

Comment: Ok, i will first have to do some AJAX revision. I will try it out and let u know.

Comment: ok, looks like i have to study jquery too! alot of studying to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is indeed using AJAX. I'd bind a function to the type event of the email field, then have it GET an action in your controller that specifically returns a JSON object with corresponding data if there is any, then fill this data into the corresponding fields using Javascript.

I have done this below using JQuery.

In your view:

notes: `controller/action` is the action it should call in the controller, also `#emailbox` is assumed to be the email form's id. `#otherbox` is a placeholder for the id's of the other form elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
   $(document).ready(function () {    
    $('input#emailbox').keyup(function () {

        // could do other stuff here, like show load bar or clear old results
        //run the ajax
        getPage();
    }); 
});


function getPage() {

    //generate the parameter for the php script
    var data = {email: $("#emailbox").val()};
    $.ajax({
        url: '/controller/action',  
        type: 'GET',        
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',     
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {  

            //add the content retrieved from ajax into whatever forms you like
            $("#otherbox").val(data.[User][information][here]);
            $("#otherbox").val(data.[User][information][here]);
            $("#otherbox").val(data.[User][information][here]);
            $("#otherbox").val(data.[User][information][here]);
        }       
    });
}                                 
 </script>
```

Note that chrome dev tools can help debug the JSON object you're getting back so you can figure out how to access the relevant data for each field.

In your controller:

```
public function searchForDetails() {
        if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
            $this->autoRender = false;
//Get the email parameter data- this is one way to do it, you could also do it plenty of other ways
$email = $this->request->query['email'];
//Get user data- I have given an example of how to do so:
$userdata = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.email' => $email,
        'recursive' => -1));
return(json_encode($userdata));
            }
    }
```

This is one way you can go about it. The work you have to do is to debug the JSON object in chrome (use command shift j to access dev tools) and figure out the layout of the arrays inside the object so you can then set the values of the individual forms. I have not tested the efficiency of this approach and you probably shouldn't do something like this if you're developing Facebook.